# Is it possible to set tbl-colwidth property in Quarto document for LaTeX output on per table basis?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, quarto

I am creating a Quarto document in R. The output is a LaTeX document (document class: scrbook). The problem I am facing is that I have some tables in the document, which has long content in the first column of the table. Because of that, the contents of the first and second columns overlap. This happens even when I keep the tbl-colwidth property to "auto".

To avoid this, I set tbl-colwidth:[20,80], which means first column would occupy 20% of the width of the page, and the 80% width would be occupied by the second column. But in this setting, there is a large gap between the two columns in most of the pages.

So, I want to know if it is possible to set the tbl-colwidth attribute on per table basis. For most of the tables, I would like to set the tbl-colwidth: auto. But only for the troublesome tables, I would like to change the tbl-colwidth manually to something like [30,70].

For example of such a table, look at this [web page](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/websites.html). On this page, there is a table under the title "Hypothesis". In this table's first column, one row has the value "enableExperimentalNewNoteButton", which is quite wide. For this kind of table, I would like to set tbl-colwidth:[30,70], or any other values needed. But for other tables, I would like to keep the tbl-colwidth: auto. Is this possible to do?

The YAML code for this document is as follows:

```
---
title: "PDF Example"
subtitle: "Example of PDF Settings in Quarto"
author: Eva
date: today
date-format: DD/MM/YYYY
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrbook
    tbl-colwidths: [20,80]
    df-print: paged
    keep-tex: true
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  message: false
  error: false
editor: visual
---
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Have you tried `tbl-colwidths` as chunk option for specific tables?

Comment: And please provide a complete example! Your given code has no tables to test on!

Comment: @shafee I never knew that it can be used as chunk option. I think it's only a global setting in YAML. Can it be done at chunk level using #| tbl-colwidth: [30,70]?

Comment: Well again, I am not sure unless you are providing me with enough code or you can test yourself!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change tbl column width manually and have a global option as a default, e.g.

```
---
title: "PDF Example"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrbook
    tbl-colwidths: [80,20]
---


| text  | number  |
|--------|--------|
| `r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`  | 555   |

: Global tbl colwidths


| text  | number  |
|--------|--------|
| `r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)` | 666   |

: Manually changed {tbl-colwidths="[50,50]"}
```

[image]